# How do I make an object that slows the player down in my platformer game?

Tags: javascript

I want to make an object like "mud" that causes the player's x and y speed and jump speed to slow down when they are standing on it, how do I do that? Here's the part of my code that deals with the player's speed right now:

```
var playerXSpeed = 7;

Player.prototype.moveX = function(step, level, keys) {
  this.speed.x = 0;
  if (keys.left) this.speed.x -= playerXSpeed;
  if (keys.right) this.speed.x += playerXSpeed;

  var motion = new Vector(this.speed.x * step, 0);
  var newPos = this.pos.plus(motion);
  var obstacle = level.obstacleAt(newPos, this.size);

  if (obstacle)
    level.playerTouched(obstacle);
  else
    this.pos = newPos;
};

var gravity = 34;
var jumpSpeed = 15:
var playerYSpeed = 6;

Player.prototype.moveY = function(step, level, keys) {
  // Accelerate player downward (always)
  this.speed.y += step * gravity;;
  var motion = new Vector(0, this.speed.y * step);
  var newPos = this.pos.plus(motion);
  var obstacle = level.obstacleAt(newPos, this.size);
  // The floor is also an obstacle -- only allow players to 
  // jump if they are touching some obstacle.
  if (obstacle) {
    level.playerTouched(obstacle);
    if (keys.up && this.speed.y > 0)
      this.speed.y = -jumpSpeed;
    else
      this.speed.y = 0;
  } else {
    this.pos = newPos;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are evaluating your obstacle logic from within your movement functions. This goes against the best practice of letting your functions have singular responsibilities. I recommend refactoring your code, letting the movement functions only do "movement", and doing your evaluations for obstacles elsewhere, a nice place would be inside of your update loop.

I will provide here a light weight refactoring to illustrate how you might think about reorganizing your code.

```
YourGameController.prototype.update = function () {
  this.referenceToYourPlayer.movePlayer(this.keysReference);
  this.referenceToYourLevel.handleCollisions();
}

var gravity = 34;
var jumpSpeed = 15:
var playerYSpeed = 6;
var playerXSpeed = 7;

Player.prototype.movePlayer = function (keys) {
  this.moveX(keys);
  this.moveY();
}

Player.prototype.moveX = function(keys) {
  this.speed.x = 0;
  if (keys.left) this.speed.x -= playerXSpeed;
  if (keys.right) this.speed.x += playerXSpeed;

  var motion = new Vector(this.speed.x * step, 0);
  var newPos = this.pos.plus(motion);
};

Player.prototype.moveY = function() {
  // Accelerate player downward (always)
  this.speed.y += step * gravity;;
  var motion = new Vector(0, this.speed.y * step);
  var newPos = this.pos.plus(motion);
};
```